# How to deal with large dataset in for loop in pySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I know , when we are firing collect() , and if the data set is too large to fit in memory, spark will crashes due to the memory problem. So what is the right approach in one of the bellow case.

I have an rdd fmap and fmap is of larger size. If I want to do some processing inside the for loop, the bellow will work if the data set is of average size. **If the data set is of larger size what will be the best approach**

```
for x,(k,v) in fmap.collect():
    st = x + " " + k +  " " + str(v)
    mynewList.append(st)
```

My intention is to format the data

```
My RDD
[
('HOMICIDE', ('2017', 1)), 
('DECEPTIVE PRACTICE', ('2015', 10)), 
('DECEPTIVE PRACTICE', ('2014', 3)), 
('DECEPTIVE PRACTICE', ('2017', 14)), 
('ROBBERY', ('2017', 1))
]
Expected result 
=============
[
('HOMICIDE', '2017', 1), 
('DECEPTIVE PRACTICE', '2015', 10), 
('DECEPTIVE PRACTICE', '2014', 3), 
('DECEPTIVE PRACTICE', '2017', 14), 
('ROBBERY', '2017', 1)
]
```

Comment: the solution is not to collect your data.

Comment: Sir, I cant iterate RDD thru a for loop right , if I do that it will throw
TypeError: 'PipelinedRDD' object is not iterable . 
So any alternative please ?

Comment: You can't iterate on RDDs. What is it you are trying to do exactly ? Like stated by @mtoto the approach is not correct.

Comment: ( I updated the question section , for the expected result) 
Here actually I want to change the format for RDD. So I feel for loop will be an easy approach , so tried on that... 

My RDD
[
('HOMICIDE', ('2017', 1)), 
('DECEPTIVE PRACTICE', ('2015', 10)), 
('DECEPTIVE PRACTICE', ('2014', 3)), 
('DECEPTIVE PRACTICE', ('2017', 14)), 
('ROBBERY', ('2017', 1))
]
Expected result 
=============
[
('HOMICIDE', '2017', 1), 
('DECEPTIVE PRACTICE', '2015', 10), 
('DECEPTIVE PRACTICE', '2014', 3), 
('DECEPTIVE PRACTICE', '2017', 14), 
('ROBBERY', '2017', 1)
]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR** Don't `collect`. I you do, and process data on the driver, there is no reason to use Spark. `collect` is useful for testing, but has negligible value in otherwise.

Just use `map`. Python 2:

```
rdd.map(lambda (x, (k,v)): x + " " + k +  " " + str(v))
```

Python 3:

```
rdd.map(lambda xkv: xkv[0] + " " + xkv[1][0] +  " " + str(xkv[1][1]))
```

Version independent:

```
def f(xkv):
    (x, (k, v)) = xkv
     return x + " " + k +  " " + str(v)

rdd.map(f)
```

To get `tuples` replace:

```
x + " " + k +  " " + str(v)
```

with:

```
(x, k, v)
```

or

```
(xkv[0], xkv[1][0], str(xkv[1][1]))
```

Comment: LostInOverflow is that you ?

Comment: Got it worked with the first option ( I used Python2 ) . So In my understanding , for most of the time we should use collect only for result . I mean to ask , just for easy calculation etc... for simplicity we should not use collect, for moving data from rdd to local. am I right

Comment: @SachinSukumaran `collect` should be used on **small** data to bring your data from the worker nodes to local.